# How to resolve no supported encrypted found while doing 'composer install'?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm new to laravel and I want to learn it. I am trying to clone a `github` repository. The repository tells me I need to clone it, and then to run the '**composer install**' command. But I get the following error:

> [**RuntimeException**]
>     No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1

I tried searching for this error on google and it told me to change the cipher to '**AES-256-CBC'**. But when I checked the cipher it has the '**AES-256-CBC**'.

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: do you have the openssl extension installed?

Comment: check your `.env` file,it has this `APP-KEY` filled!

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman the repository only has an .env.example file. should I change this to .env ?

Comment: On which laravel version you are working?

Comment: yes,you should change it to `.env`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need **.env** file:

You can download [**env.example**](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example), rename it to `.env` and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials etc.

**Note:** If you already have `.env.example`, just rename it to `.env`

Don't forget to When you use the `php artisan key:generate` it will generate the new key to your `.env` file

Comment: I renamed the .env.example file to .env

but when I try php artisan key:generate it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @straatrakker Share your `.env` file code with us, I think you made a change on it

Comment: After any changes of `.env` edit, You can clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @straatrakker This is wrong, you can download `env.example`, there is a link in my answer, download and rename to `.env`

Comment: I downloaded the .env.example and renamed it to .env but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205578/discussion-between-udhav-sarvaiya-and-straatrakker).

Answer (score 1):

check your `.env` file,it has this **APP-KEY** filled!,if not there-then run this command.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

And after that check your `.env` file, there should be this type of line

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY = ***keys_go_here***
....
```

and in your `config/app.php`,is there present this code of line.

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY')
```

After that do what you supposed to do previously.

Comment: I only have an .env.example flile. Should I change this to .env? 
When I try the php artisan key:generate command I still get the same error except for the

 'Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1'

Comment: First you need to copy `.env.example` to `.env` new file,after that run `php artisan key:generate`-lastly you may do what you want to do,i mean start to clone from `github` and run `composer install`

Comment: I have this:
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

Comment: `APP_KEY = ***keys_go_here***` is this filled, then just `'key' => env('APP_KEY')` remove any other string,in your case `SomeRandomString`

Comment: no it's not filled. so I should delete the SomeRandomString ?

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` command should be generate key,what was return after this command on console...if possible add that screenshot with your post.

Comment: it gives me the same error... [RuntimeException] No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your console.first copy the .env.example

```
sudo cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

if php artisan key:generate give permission error then giv permission to your .env

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .env
```

then

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy `.env.example` file and make new file in same directory name as `.env`
and then run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

first, install the Composer, then go to the project folder in cmd and run this command:

```
composer update
```